# tclhttpd cannot source scripts in custom without a strange hack

Tags: tcl

I am running tclhttpd with TCL 8.5 using tcllib v1.3 and am having a very strange problem:

```
# tclsh8.5 bin/httpd.tcl 
<Snip>
/home/enigma/tclhttpd3.5.1/bin/../custom/dodirs.tcl: couldn't read file "/home/enigma/tclhttpd3.5.1/bin/../custom/dodirs.tcl": no such file or directory
/home/enigma/tclhttpd3.5.1/bin/../custom/faq.tcl: couldn't read file "/home/enigma/tclhttpd3.5.1/bin/../custom/faq.tcl": no such file or directory
/home/enigma/tclhttpd3.5.1/bin/../custom/hello.tcl: couldn't read file "/home/enigma/tclhttpd3.5.1/bin/../custom/hello.tcl": no such file or directory
/home/enigma/tclhttpd3.5.1/bin/../custom/mypage.tcl: couldn't read file "/home/enigma/tclhttpd3.5.1/bin/../custom/mypage.tcl": no such file or directory
```

So, I edited the file `bin/httpdthread.tcl` in the "Load customer code" section and added the following debug:

```
foreach f [lsort -dictionary [glob -nocomplain [file join $Config(library) *.tcl]]] {
        ###### START MY DEBUG
        if {1} {
            Stderr "Considering $f..."
            if { [file isfile $f]  == 1} {
                Stderr "File looks good"
            } else {
                Stderr "ERROR"
            }
        }
        ###### END MY DEBUG

        if {[string compare [file tail $f] "pkgIndex.tcl"] == 0} {
            Stderr "Continuing NOT loading"
             continue
        } elseif {[catch {source $f} err]} {
             Stderr "$f: $err"
        } elseif {$Config(debug)} {
             Stderr "Loaded [file tail $f]: $err"
        }
    }
```

With this small addition of debug the server finds the above files and starts to run correctly. Does anyone know what could be the issue? I don't think my extra debug should have changed the behaviour. Does `[file is file...]` somehow affect the `source` in the later `if` statement? If I set the debug to `if {0} {...` the file errors occur again.

Comment: Does this directory exist? /home/enigma/tclhttpd3.5.1/bin/../custom

Comment: Any good reason to use the very old tcllib 1.3 version, 1.16 is the current one?

Comment: @Glen Yeah the file exists. And the `file isfile` returns true.
@Sclenk Its there by legacy... system is tested with it, can't upgrade for just my little bit alas. Thanks both for you responses

Comment: A little more info... currently, for test, running tclhttpd scripts from a remote mount... gonna make this locally mounted to see if this is causing the failure

Comment: You'd be better off using `glob -nocomplain -directory $Config(library) *.tcl` instead that thing with `file join`, but that probably won't fix your issues…

Comment: Which _exact_ version of Tcl are you using? I'm just wondering if you've hit one of the bugs in the virtual FS interface layer.

Comment: possible. tcl 8.5, tcllib 1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be that it did not like running the tclhttp server from a remotely mounted directory. I was doing this as a quick n dirty test to see if the server would run on my target...

Copying the tclhttp on target's local storage removed this error. What is strange though is that the `file isfile` command was somehow allowing the TCL to source the custom command TCl scripts from the remotely mounted location! Can't explain that bit!

Comment: Oooh, remote mounts. They're pretty nasty at times, unfortunately: they're often incomplete in their handling of filesystem semantics and it's in areas like testing if a file exists that the problems often surface.

Comment: It's a little strange though that the test-if-file-exists says "yes file does exists" but the later `source` says "file does not exist" :)